# replace spaces with underscores in href attribute

Tags: html, command-prompt

I have replaced all the spaces in file names with underscores.The files were around 800 in number.I used Replace Pioneer for the same.But the problem is how should I replace those files names in the href fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first thought you might try using the unix find and sed commands. However, doing so would require strong knowledge of regex and likely would end up being a lot more than a simple one-liner. Due to the fact that you are not simply replacing one known string and need to avoid replacing spaces outside of the filenames I would recommend to do this by writing a script using an xml parser.

Here's the basic outline of what you would need to do if you were to write such a script in Python:

1) Import the [OS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [ElementTree lib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html): `import os` and `from optparse import OptionParser import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`
2) Get the list of HTML files you would like to modify using Python's "[listdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)" or "[glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)".
3) For each file get all `img` or `a` tags depending on which tags contain the `href` attributes which need to be changed. For example, you can get all `img` tags in a file like this:

```
file = ET.parse(filename)
doc = file.getroot()
imgs = doc.findall('.//img')
```

4) And finally, for each `img` or `a` tag, replace all spaces with underscores in the tags `href` attribute.

I hope this helps. Let me know if I've misunderstood your question. Additionally, it might be possible to solve this using the tool you mentioned or a similar one, although I find it unlikely and it will likely require a fair amount of regex.

Comment: This is a valuable answer.You got my query correctly and I will give it a try.Thankx...!!!